# How to create async.auto-like promises chain?

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird

Here is the code I have:

```js
async.auto({
    client: service.findClient,
    existingChat: ['client', service.findChat],
    chat: ['client', 'existingChat', service.createChat]
}, (err) => {
    if (err) return service.handleError(err);
    service.emitChatEvent();
    service.editMenu();
});
```

What is the best way to handle it by using Bluebird Promises?

The most confusing thing to me is this line:

```
 chat: ['client', 'existingChat', service.createChat]
```

`service.createChat` should have an access to both `service.findClient()` and `service.findChat()` results.

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself? I can't tell what that code does, so it's hard to know how to rewrite it using a different methodology - you at least have a clue as to what it's purpose is

Comment: @JaromandaX I've updated my question.

Comment: Your solution is looking good. If it works, why not post it as an answer instead of a question update?

Comment: You don't really need the `return`, though. `.then((client) => [client, service.findChat(client)])`

Comment: If you don't mind an extra lib you could check out this https://github.com/backhand/auto-promise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I've found the solution:

```
service.findClient(message)
    .then((client) => [client, service.findChat(client)])
    .spread(service.createChat)
    .then(service.emitChatEvent)
    .then(service.editMenu)
    .catch(service.handleError);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could look at other already created modules like [async-bluebird](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async-bluebird), or you could roll your own. By your question, it looks as though you don't necessarily need your own `auto()` promise implementation, just a working version of your example. In that case, you could achieve it by using a combination of chaining, and the `all()` function. For example (*untested and off the top of my head*):

```
let fc = service.findClient(message);
Promise.all([fc, fc.then(service.findChat)])
       .then(service.createChat);
```

Firstly, I create a promise from the `findClient` function, and then I create an array of required promises for the `all` function. The first is the initial promise, while the second is a chained version of the first into the second function. When both of those have completed, the `all` function returns the results of both promises into a results array.